# Is there any word in English to say "additional stuff" for free?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

There is a term in Portuguese "choro" or "chorinho", that can be used in a context like this:

> O barman me serviu uma dose the whiskey e deu um chorinho

meaning

> The barman served me a dose of whiskey (I have paid for) plus a little bit more for free.

In Brazil people expect barmen to serve a little bit more that the dose they paid. Barmen (bartender) that don't do that are not well seen.

Is there a word that can be used in that context, or a construction that means the above, without using the ugly construction I have used to explain?

Comment: In AmE, we have a “heavy pour”, which means pouring more than they should and thus making the glass heavier than it should be.

Comment: can you post an answer giving an example on how the phrase should be written? thanks

Comment: You might also say "I was served a generous measure of whiskey" or "... given a generous measure ...".

Comment: "generous" is good....In British "culture" this is unheard of, since there is an odd obsession with exact measures.  So you get 25ml (and not ml more).  The idea of a barman "pouring whisky" (from a bottle) is pretty rare too, an optic is used so that the barman can't cheat you of even a ml

Comment: We get a dose of medicine but a _shot_ or _measure_ of spirits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Portuguese seems to be literally "cry (noun)", the literal translation doesn't work well.  There doesn't seem to be a noun that fits well, but you can use an adjective (with the noun "shot" rather than "dose"):

> The barman served me a generous shot of whisky.

American English uses "pour" as a noun or a verb, so you can speak of a "heavy pour", or "pour the whiskey heavy". "long" is also used in the same sense.

Culturally the US and UK are quite different.  Bartenders in the US will often pour heavy, in expectation of a generous tip.  In the UK, tipping bartender is rare, and serving non-standard amounts is illegal (and can get the bar closed by the police)

Comment: ah I see. thanks for the help... you heavy pour on that explanation. 